# 64 bit configured project does not seem to generate 64 bit exe in bin file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process, 64-bit

I created an application in Visual Studio 2013 and I wanted to build it as 64 bit application. I configured my project as 64 bit app, followed steps from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx). Now the problems:

***If I run the application from VS it works fine (as a 64 bit application).***

***If I run the executable generated in bin it works like a 32 bit application.***

**Important mentions:**

The application has to get all running processes and display them in a grid with Process Name and File Name (path to the executable).
[image]

*This is what the grid looks like when I run from VS*

[image]

*And this is what the grid looks like when I run the .exe from the bin*

I know the app works like a 32 bit application because I try to access *.MainModule.FileName* to find the path to the exe and a 32 bit process will throw a Win32 exception when trying to access a 64 bit process. I handle that exception but I can't find the path and I need it.

***I need a way to generate the .exe in the bin as a 64 bit application, or atleast understand why it is not working like a 64 bit application if the configuration is made for 64 bit.***

Answer (score 0):

Different project configurations have different output folders. Your x86 configuration still uses the original bin folder that you're looking in, but the new x64 configuration is going to dump its output in a different folder.

Visual Studio tracks the output folder for the current configuration, so it is launching the correct EXE. But when you launch it yourself, you're looking in the wrong folder. You are running the 32-bit EXE, which never got changed.

To see where the output path is, go to your project's Properties (in the Solution Manager), and click on the "Build" tab. You should see it listed near the bottom, in the textbox labeled "Output path".

By default, x86 uses `bin\Debug\`, while x64 uses `bin\x64\Debug\`. (These are relative paths, relative to your solution directory.)

Comment: I launched the exe from the bin/x64/Release directory from the start, and I kept an eye on the 'Date modified' column to see if the exe was generated when I built the solution. That exe was not working how I expected.